# SqlException 'invalid column name' for composite key tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have sql tables with composite keys that I'm trying to pull into EF Code First models, but I'm getting `'invalid column name'` errors. A typical schema in sql server management studio might look like this...

```
PLAN 
-Columns
  -EnterpriseID (PK, bigint, notnull)
  -PlanID (PK, uniqueidentifier, notnull)
  -column3 (uniqueidentifier)
  -column4 (uniqueidentifier)
-Keys
 PK_Plans
```

...and then my model would look something like...

```
public class Plan
    {
        [Column(Order=0), Key]
        public long      EnterpriseID               { get; set; }
        [Column(Order=1), Key]
        public Guid      PlanID               { get; set; }
        public Guid    Column3                       { get; set; }
        public Guid      Column4                    { get; set; }
    }
```

Seems straightforward, but I keep getting this error for *second composite key* of each such table. So for example, for the above I would get ***"Invalid column name 'Column3'", "Invalid column name 'Column4'"***

In other words I'm getting the error for each uniqueidentifier column mapped to a Guid property *after* the first such column, which is PlanID.

Comment: I haven't used this, but the samples I can doing this have the attributes in the reverse order: [Key, Column(Order=0 or 1)]. Is that worth a try?

Comment: I think that would give me a compile error if that were the case, right? Now I'm also seeing more about the error, it's giving me 'invalid column name' for each uniqueidentifier column *after* the first one, which are all mapped to Guid types.

Comment: It might not give you an error...

Comment: I think I know why. I'm using test data in which uniqueidentifier values repeat *within* a table row, like say column3 = "aaaa-aaaa-aaaa" AND column4 = "aaaa-aaaa-aaaa" for one Plan row. Think that may be the problem?

Comment: If that generates a dup PK (sounds like it does) then that would definitely cause an error!

Comment: Wouldn't generate a duplicate PK, since the EnterpriseID is an identity incremented by 1 (never repeated)

Comment: And PlanID are unique across rows, it's only that uniqueidentifier columns repeat values *within rows*, if that makes any sense.

Comment: No, having the same values in different columns in the same row shouldn't cause an error. Do column3, column4 exist currently in the DB? What DBtype are they?

Comment: I found the error actually, like an idiot I had misspelled the column name in my Fluent mapping haha. Could have sworn I double checked that before I posted. Thanks Simon.

Comment: No problem. Good you found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you double checked your case on the field names? I see in your example Column 3/4 have a capital 'C' in the model and a lower case 'c' in the plan.

Comment: Ended up fixing this a few days back, I think it *was* a misspelled column name in Fluent mapping, actually...